# Tunning python plots without running full script over and over

Tags: python

I am getting some stock data via an api, which i then plot onto various graphs. To tune the graphs and to test various plotting, i dont want to run the full script calling the api to always get the data again and again.
Is there a way to keep the data and just work on the plotting?

Thanks

I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Have you tried to pickle the data and load them for visualizations?

Comment: Maybe try using Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: @AndreySobolev would that also work for creating a dash application?

Comment: No, I thought you just need to play with the data. If you need to create a Dash app, then you can either store the data on the frontend, or pickle it into a Redis DB, as described [here](https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks)